# How to use NFS to share a mounted drive?

Tags: networking, mount, hard-drive, nfs

I have a SSD where I store my OS and I have a 1 TB hard-drive where I store my files (mounted at /run/media/owner/ExtraHDD/). I want to share my files. I can share my SSD (such as /home/owner) using NFS but if I try to do the same for my 1 TB hard-drive (/run/media/owner/ExtraHDD/), I get access denied error when I try to mount it on the client.

Here is my /etc/exports:

```
/home/owner                    192.168.1.1/24(rw,sync,nohide)
/run/media/owner/ExtraHDD      192.168.1.1/24(rw,sync,nohide)
```

Answer (score 5):

This can be achieved by enabling cross mounting. Just add `crossmnt` to your exported entry in /etc/exports

```
/srv        *(rw,fsid=0,no_subtree_check,crossmnt)
```

And don't forget to issue the appropriate command for the changes to take effect as shown bellow:

```
$ exportfs -ra
```

Comment: Your solution saved me a lot of hair pulling. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Have you try this one? [Setting Up NFS](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SettingUpNFSHowTo)